# How to remove the keys from a multi-dimensional associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, associative-array

I have an associative array which has the following format:

```
array (
  'Shopping and fashion' => 
  array (
    'childData' => 
    array (
      'Beauty' => 
      array (
        'childData' => 
        array (
          'Cosmetics' => 
          array (
            'id' => '6002839660079',
            'name' => 'Cosmetics',
            'parentName' => 'Beauty',
          ),
          'Tattoos' => 
          array (
            'id' => '6003025268985',
            'name' => 'Tattoos',
            'parentName' => 'Beauty',
          ),),))))
```

I want to remove the keys from the array.
For this I am using :

```
array_values($my_data)
```

However, this only works for the topmost level of array, which in this case is "Shopping and fashion". It converts that to index 0.
How can I do the same for every array inside the index too?

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
array (
    0 =>
        array (
            'childData' =>
                array (
                    0 =>
                        array (
                            'childData' =>
                                array (
                                    0 =>
                                        array (
                                            'id' => '6002839660079',
                                            'name' => 'Cosmetics',
                                            'parentName' => 'Beauty',
                                        ),
                                    1 =>
                                        array (
                                            'id' => '6003025268985',
                                            'name' => 'Tattoos',
                                            'parentName' => 'Beauty',
                                        ),
                                ),
                            'name' => 'Beauty',
                            'id' => '6002867432822',
                            'parentName' => 'Shopping and fashion',
                        ),)))
```

The array I have has many different arrays on the parent level and many more array inside them so using for each is posing a problem as the number of "childData",i.e child arrays inside parent arrays are varying.

Could recursion be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know built-in function, but maybe this function would help you?

```
function array_values_recursive( $array ) {
    $newArray = [];
    foreach ( $array as $key => $value ) {
        if ( is_array( $value ) ) {
            $newArray[] = array_values_recursive( $value );
        } else {
            $newArray[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $newArray;
}
```

Comment: It comes close to the answer but not perfect. it's making the data inside arrays to indexed too.
For example:
```
Cosmetics' => 
          array (
            'id' => '6002839660079',
            'name' => 'Cosmetics',
            'parentName' => 'Beauty',)
```
changed to :
```
array (
  0 => '6002839660079',
  1 => 'Cosmetics',
  2 => 'Beauty',
)
```

Comment: Should be `$newArray[] = $value;`

Comment: @nice_dev But it will return return as the first answer. Without keys...

Comment: @nice_dev Here what it will return according to your comment http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4ad42251b2aa27125e16fe8d93c83f49dc4be265

Comment: @UrmatZhenaliev Now that I see the output, OP wants a linear array of values. This seems to recursively remove keys.

Comment: @PHP_Newbie Edit your post with expected output to avoid any confusion.

Comment: @nice_dev I have added the expected output

Comment: @UrmatZhenaliev I added the expected output. Thanks

Comment: @PHP_Newbie Is the answer is correct, could you please accept the answer? If you don't mind of course

Comment: yes surely. @UrmatZhenaliev Thank you so much for helping me with this
The update works for me